# Как задать переменное количество именованных параметров SQL-запроса для TUniQuery?

Tags: sql, delphi

Например есть такая функция как **ExecSQLEx** и в неё можно передавать переменное кол-во параметров:

```
if not DataModule1.UniConnection1.InTransaction then 
DataModule1.UniConnection1.StartTransaction;          
try          
  //тут выполняемый запрос
  DataModule1.UniConnection1.ExecSQLEx('UPDATE ...','name_parametr1', parametr1, 'name_parametr2', parametr2,'name_parametr3', parametr3 ...);
  DataModule1.UniConnection1.Commit;  
except on E: Exception do
  begin
    DataModule1.UniConnection1.Rollback;
  end;
end;
```

И ты можешь создать функцию, которая устраняет кучу шаблонного кода (чтобы не писать его каждый раз)

```
class function myExecSQLEx (SQL:string; params: array of Variant): String; 
...
 function TForm1.myExecSQLEx (SQL:string; params: array of Variant): String;
 begin
  if not DataModule1.UniConnection1.InTransaction then
  DataModule1.UniConnection1.StartTransaction;
  try

    DataModule1.UniConnection1.ExecSQLEx(SQL, params) //просто передаётся произвольное кол-во именованных параметров
    DataModule1.UniConnection1.Commit;
    Result:='ok';
  except on E: Exception do
    begin
      DataModule1.UniConnection1.Rollback;
      Result:='Ошибка: '+ E.Message;
    end;
  end;
 end;
```

Но это всё работает хорошо для функции ExecSQLEx, а так как я выполняю запрос  именно в компоненте TUniQuery, то там есть только точное перечисление заранее указанных параметров:

```
...
UniQuery1:TUniQuery;
...
UniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name_parametr1').AsInteger := parametr1;
UniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name_parametr2').AsInteger := parametr2;
...
UniQuery1.Open;
```

Можно ли как то сделать для UniQuery передачу произвольного количества именованных параметров?

Comment: А что мешает динамически формировать сам запрос? Тогда будет у вас столько параметров, сколько захотите.
Какие исходные данные? Откуда берутся параметры и сам запрос, в который эти параметры нужно подставить?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАлександров Формировать динамически могу, но передача через параметры - обязательна т.к. защита от SQL-инъекций, а вот на переменном количестве именованных параметров я и споткнулся.

Comment: Делается по аналогии с Exec, который вы выше привели:
    **UniQuery1.sql.text := 'update table1 set param1 = :param1, param2 = :param2';**
    **UniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('param1').AsInteger := parametr1;**
    **UniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('param2').AsInteger := parametr2;**
Возможно, еще нужно будет сделать **UniQuery1.Prepare**. Не работал с UniQuery, поэтому затрудняюсь точно сказать.

Comment: Это не аналогия, "UniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name_parametr2').AsInteger := parametr2;" это строка - программный код, как я вам его сгенерирую то, ведь параметров неизвестно сколько может быть, а в случае ExecSQLEx это массив параметров, просто перечисляешь их через запятую и всё.

Comment: Сгенерировать строку можно, например, в цикле по массиву параметров.

Comment: Зачем мне генерировать delphi-строки? Ведь речь дальше идёт  именно о delphi-коде, без него ты не передашь переменное количество именованных параметров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно именно именованные параметры, то можно попробовать использовать экземпляр класса `TParams`, вроде он не сильно связан с `TDataSet`. Или передавать список `TList<TPair<string, varinat>>`

Но если делать по аналогии, то просто приходимся по параметрам. Следим за соответствием количества, которым значение не нашлось что-то делаем (очищаем, значением по умолчанию).

Код для совпадающего количества.

```pascal
procedure myExecSQLInQuery (UniQuery1:TUniQuery; params: array of Variant); 
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to UniQuery1.ParamCount - 1 do
    UniQuery1.Params[i].Value := params[i];
end;
```

Компонент может создаваться внутри как с готовым запросом, так и текст запроса можно передавать из вне.

Comment: Проверку на чётность добавить, чтобы кол-во имён параметров соответствовало кол-ву самих параметров и можно использовать, спасибо!